# Shunt ohmmeter question

Tags: resistors, shunt, ohmmeter

I have a question concerning this shunt ohmmeter:

[image: Ohmmeter schematic]

If we only want to use the \$R \times 1\$ gauge, we have the following circuit:

[image: Simplified ohmmeter schematic]

I want to know **what indication would appear on the ohmmeter if I put a resistor \${R}_{x} = 24 \Omega\$**

So far, I've found that I can find \$I_m\$ using the following equation:

\$I_m=\frac{15}{16995 {R}_{x} + 400580}\$

Which means that **\$I_m = 18.72\mu A \approx \frac{FSD}{2}\$**.

My professor has said that the scale is arithmetic and has a maximum value of \$10 \Omega\$, so that the indication is \$R = 5 \Omega\$.

**Why this value is different from \$24 \Omega\$ ? Is it because the scale of the ohmmeter is not good ?**

Comment: How is this unclear?

Comment: @laptop2d Ever measured a resistor of \$ 24 \Omega \$ to get a value of \$ 5 \Omega \$ ?

Comment: It was more of a message to the moderators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with you that when at 0 (zero) Ohms the meter is at full scale (37.5 uA) it must be at half of the full scale when \$R_x\$ is 24 ohms as that halves the current \$I_b\$ so must also halve the current \$I_m\$.

So for this circuit 24 ohms is half-scale.

Now let's look at an analog multimeter with a R x 1 scale:

[image]

And another one:

[image]

Note how for the top one 5 ohms is at half-scale.

While for the bottom one 10 ohms is at half scale when using the R x 1 range.

Obviously it depends on the circuit inside the meter what value corresponds to half scale. For the circuit from your question half scale would be 24 ohms.

Also notice how high ohm values are at the left (small) and 0 ohms is at the right. This also means that the maximum value of a an ohms range is infinity.

Your professor stating that the scale has a maximum of 10 ohms is simply **wrong**. The maximum is at 0 ohms as then \$I_b\$ and thus \$I_m\$ will be at maximum.

Answer (score 3):

You're correct that 24 Ohms gives FSD/2 and 0 ohms gives FSD in the x1R scale.

The maximum value if you consider of 1% FSD will be much higher R for 1%= 0.18uA, since deflection is **inversely related to R spanning  3 decades** in the fine graticules in each decade range of 1x,10x,100x,1kx,10k

So this meter with 24 ohms mid scale might have a resolution of 0.25 Ohm per division near 0 and a max reading of 250 ohms and maybe 500 near 1% with open cct. at 0% deflection.

Now for 5 points compute the most critical value resistor in the box.;) on the 1xR scale and it's tolerance.